# Headless Service stops working after closing ejected expo app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to use HeadlessJS from react-native with expokit (expo ejected) app.

I wanted to run an JS function when app is closed. but the service is closing with app.

**Edit:**
Got to know that, Headless is not at all working in expokit RN app, JS function is not accessible to android.

#### HeadlessTaskService.java

```
import ...
public class HeadlessTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
    @Nullable
    protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "OfflineSync",
            Arguments.fromBundle(extras),
            6000,
            false
        );
      }
    }
}
```

#### OfflineSync.java

```
public class OfflineSync extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "OfflineSync";
    private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public OfflineSync(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void toggleService(Boolean start){
        if(start.equals(true)){
            startService();
        }else{
            stopService();
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void startService() {
        this.reactContext.startService(new Intent(this.reactContext, AndroidService.class));
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void stopService() {
        this.reactContext.stopService(new Intent(this.reactContext, AndroidService.class));
    }
}
```

calling *toggleService(true/false)* to start stop service

#### OfflineSyncPackage.java

```
public class OfflineSyncPackage implements ReactPackage, Package {
    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(
                new OfflineSync(reactContext)
        );
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

#### AndroidService.java

```
public class AndroidService extends Service {
private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, HeadlessTaskService.class);
            context.startService(myIntent);
            HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }
    };
}
```

#### BootUpReceiver

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, AndroidService.class));
    }
}
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".AndroidService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" />
      <service android:name=".HeadlessTaskService" />
      <receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
```

#### MainApplication.java

```
@Override
  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new OfflineSyncPackage()
    );
  }
```

#### App.js

```
HeadlessFn = () =>{
 ...
}
export default function App() {
NativeModules.OfflineSync.toggleService(true); //To Start service
...
}

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('OfflineSync', () => HeadlessFn) // Registering HLJ
AppRegistry.registerComponent("main", () => App);
```

In normal react-native app the behaviour looks fine, but in expo app the HJS service closes with app.

Comment: check the full package names in manifest and use low case for package name:<service android:name="com.locationlistener.service.YourService" />

Comment: Thanks for replay @Oleg , you mean folder name? from `.OfflineSync.HeadlessTaskService` to `.offlinesync.HeadlessTaskService`?